# Grid View for Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there any package for grid view for Meteor js?

I am looking for a package that generates a data grid from collections including paging and sorting like the ones from ASP.NET grid view.

I have created one but I think it would be better to use a package that is well maintained in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

give this a shot if you need paging and sorting  : 
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular

I can vouch for the package maintainer, I'm using one of his packages for almost a year and it's quite good and he's been responsive to issues.